# Does China censor online discussions of female orgasms?

Tags: sexuality, china, social-media, censorship

A Washington Post [article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/asia_pacific/china-clubhouse-blocked-internet/2021/02/08/769c5134-69c0-11eb-a66e-e27046e9e898_story.html) describes how people in China were recently discussing certain taboo subjects using the Clubhouse app:

> They asked questions about the protests in Hong Kong, reports of mass detentions of Uighurs in the western region of Xinjiang, the 1989 Tiananmen Square massacre and female orgasm — all topics that would normally be quickly censored on any Chinese social media platform.

I know that China censors online discussion of Hong Kong, Uighurs, and Tiananmen Square. But does China really censor discussion of female orgasms?

Comment: Is the male orgasm discussed on Chinese social media platforms? I am suprised that discussion of any kind of massacre is *taboo* as opposed to *censored*. There is a  difference: the former is from social norms, the latter is by the state.

Comment: @WeatherVane: As I understand it, censorship doesn't just involve deleting online content but rather enacting retribution.  The censored topics are taboo in the sense that folks are afraid to be associated with discussing them.

Comment: China recently [changed the subtitles](https://www.cnn.com/2022/02/12/entertainment/china-lgbt-friends-television-lesbian-censorship-scli-intl/index.html) of a "Friends" episode that mentioned women having "multiple orgasms" to "women have endless gossips".

Answer (score 3):

Hard to say for sure; probably yes to some extent.

While one can find articles even in the [Global Times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Times) on [sex toys for women](https://www.globaltimes.cn/content/1012116.shtml), at least back in 2016, there seems to be a less tolerant attitude among censors more recently, as [reported by NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/06/02/world/asia/china-beijing-sex-education-women.html) in 2019:

> Not long after Ms. Zhao moved back to China in 2015, she started Yummy, whose app features an online shop that sells lingerie and sex toys designed specifically for women, including vibrators and handcuffs.
>
> Since March, Yummy has also organized six female orgasm workshops in cities across China. The workshops come at a fraught time for feminism here. In recent years, as the Communist Party under the leadership of Xi Jinping has tightened its grip on civil society, the space for activism — including feminist activism — has shrunk rapidly.
>
> While Yummy and Ms. Zhao are not political, **they have encountered problems with Chinese censors. Ms. Zhao estimates that 25 percent of Yummy’s online articles are deleted by censors, who tend to be especially sensitive to sexually explicit content**. Recently, the control “has only gotten stricter,” she said.

It seems the focus of the censors (in this regard) is on sexually explicit materials, but that can have a rather broad interpretation according to this (2018) [SCMP article](https://www.scmp.com/abacus/culture/article/3028565/chinas-anti-porn-office-cracks-down-videos-women-whispering) on censoring [ASMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASMR) materials:

> fans in China were dealt a blow last week when the country’s anti-pornography office ordered a number of platforms to remove a lot of ASMR content -- because they say some are akin to softcore porn. [...]
>
> ASMR is even referred to as “in-skull orgasm” by many Chinese internet users, highlighting the sexual image of some videos.

Comment: I can't address the details, but I have been in a few sex shops in China.  The sex toys for sale seem akin to what you would find elsewhere, although not the variety (but that's no surprise, it's rare to find the variety of anything that you find in the US), but the packaging is incredibly tame by US standards--to the point you might not even realize you're looking at a sex toy.

Comment: I have also had the experience of trying to locate China's Museum of Sex.  (Note: Gone.)  We had the exact address, my wife speaks native-level Chinese and it still took something like an hour to locate--because a sign would have been unacceptable.  The government didn't mind the museum's contents, just identifying it.